# After the Occupation of Janis will I be able to unequip Anelace and Kurt?

Tags: trails-in-the-sky-sc

I only have just about enough endgame equipment for maybe 3 males and 2 females. The game gives me the opportunity, at the start of this segment, to unequip other characters to equip Anelace and Kurt, who just joined me.

[image][image]

Will I get a chance to do the same juggling in reverse at the end of the mission? I'm pretty sure that I'd get a zero field generators back for plot reasons, but I'm not so sure about the rest.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of this mission, Anelace and Kurt leave you. All of their equipment and belongings stay in your inventory. Free quartz!